# Reading unparsed GET and POST parameters in Django

Tags: django, post, get

I would like to read GET and POST parameters of HttpRequest as unparsed string.

Urlencoding already parsed HttpRequest.POST or HttpRequest.GET is not an option, because that might result to different string than the original one.

I already found GET parameters from HttpRequest.META["QUERY_STRING"] and POST parameters from HttpRequest.body but somehow they feel kind of hacky, at least the GET case. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you have it now?

Comment: I don't know, it just feels hacky.. But if you think it's the best available, then I'll just keep using that.

Comment: What's hacky about using the two attributes on a request that are supposed to contain the raw query data? `request.META['QUERY_STRING']` and `request.body` are definitely the way to go.